# Oracle recommendations for high volume writes and low volume read

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

Is there some general guidelines online on how to tweak oracle for doing a high number of inserts and low number of reads?

All the answers below are pretty good recommendations. I have to clarify the following things. I am using 10g and this is an absolute requirement that we use Oracle. I am also more interested in oracle instance parameters for tuning (perhaps some different locking policies).

Comment: In terms of parameters or db design (or both?)   :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume you want to do an excessive high number of inserts, so that you simply want to just ignore all other kinds of operations just to get those inserts to complete, without problems.

First, have you completely ruled out other types of databases? There are systems like industry databases that cope very well with massive amounts of inserts, typically used to receive and store data from equipment that is measuring something in a factory environment. Oracle is a relational database, it might not be the right type of software for your needs.

Having said that, let's assume you can, or will, or should, use Oracle. The very first thing you need to do is to consider all the various types of data you need to make this assumption about. If they're all about the same kind of data, you need 1 table, and it need to be lean and mean regarding inserts.

The optimal way do that is to do the following:

1. do not add any indexes on this table at all, if you need a primary key, that's the only index you want
2. if you need to do reads against this table, consider having a shadow table with indexes that you do reads, lookups, and aggregates against. If this doesn't have to be up-to-the-millisecond updated, consider a periodic batch job to update it with data from the master table. This will disturb the master table with read-locks as little as possible
3. Make sure your server has fast disks. Transactional write operations will typically involve the disk at some point, so make sure that's a small bottleneck as you can get.
4. If your application is gathering data from many incoming sources, consider adding a layer in front of the database that will keep the number of concurrent connections and thus transactions to that table to a minimum. If you get a high number of write-locks on the same page for an oracle database, ultimately your performance will suffer.

If you can split up the data, consider splitting it in such a way that it is stored on different physical disks. That way, disk I/O problems won't be cross-data-type, and only affect one type of data.

In the other end of the spectrum you have a denormalized table with lots of indexes optimized for a balance between lookups and updates, and you need to find some middle-way that will get you the performance you want.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of database design put as few constraints, indexes and triggers on the table(s) you're inserting into as possible as these will all slow down the insert.

The lack of indexes will obviously hurt your SELECT performance, but it doesn't sound like this is your primary concern.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of application are we talking about?  What version of Oracle?

If you are designing a data warehouse load process, for example, you would generally want to do direct-path inserts into staging table(s), then build any necessary indexes, then do a partition exhange to load the data into the partitioned destination table.  This doesn't work as well, of course, if you are doing single-row inserts.

Depending on the Oracle version and the type of application, you may also want to enable compression on the table.  Inserts are generally cheap from a CPU standpoint, so there is probably plenty of CPU available to do the compression which can substantially decrease the amount of I/O required, which is generally going to be your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that you take your question to Tom Kyte's site, **http://asktom.oracle.com**.  You can generally find an answer there.  Otherwise, try **[Oracle's forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/main.jspa?categoryID=84)**.

Also try looking up any of Tom Kyte's books.  Suggest checking the library or your local bookstore to find the right one, to ensure that the book contains the right topics for you.  Also, **[his blog](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/)** has links to his books and some articles/discussions on each book.

I did a quick google, site:oracle.com tuning write, and found this
**[OracleAS TopLink Writing Optimization Features](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15901/tuning006.htm)**.  I realize that you might not be using TopLink but it may have some good tips.  Keywords you'll want to try using: tuning, performance, insert(s), improve.  Also through in the technology you are using like java/c++/etc.

Other tips you can try:

- using stored procedures or using them in more efficient ways.
- tweaking your server's hardware.  Faster hard drives or a specific RAID array, possibly more cpu's.
- **[Ask Tom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:12083187196917)** - some nice comments here, also links to **[Fowler's site](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/dblogic.html)**

You will probably have to start running some performance analytics on your queries/implementations to find the sweet spot for each one.  I wish I had an easy answer for you.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions for you to look into further:-

- direct path load
- block compression